# Сайт задач на C++

Tags: c++

Вроде теорию неплохо знаю, хотелось бы проверить на практике =)

Comment: http://acm.timus.ru/

Comment: Просто задачи по программированию или олимпиадные? Что больше Вас интересует?

Comment: кстати довольно интересны и простые задачи по программированию, например при изучении нового языка

Comment: Хотелось бы порешать задачи связанные с классами.

Comment: Вопрос уже поднимался: [HashCode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47392/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)